# View side by side only two declared excel workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make tool for comparing two declared workbooks. I have faced problem with part of code which would open vertical those two. Excel has built in option for that kind of action in View ribbon part, but it considers all opened workbooks.

My code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton68_Click()
Dim current As Workbook
Dim prior As Workbook
Dim sheetname As String
Dim celladdr As String




'On Error GoTo errhandler
 Set current = ActiveWorkbook

 Set prior = Application.Workbooks(TextBox8.Value)

 sheetname = current.ActiveSheet.Name
 celladdr = activecell.Address



 prior.Sheets(sheetname).Activate
 prior.Sheets(sheetname).Range(celladdr).Activate
 current.Activate

 Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical

 Exit Sub
 errhandler:
 MsgBox ("Cannot find loaded workbook, please try again!")
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton71_Click()
Dim current As Workbook
Dim prior As Workbook
Dim sheetname As String
Dim celladdr As String




On Error GoTo errhandler
Set current = ActiveWorkbook

If TextBox8.Value = "" Then
MsgBox ("Prior file is not loaded! Textbox at the top is empty, please load file 
first.")
Exit Sub
Else


Set prior = Application.Workbooks(TextBox8.Value)

sheetname = current.ActiveSheet.Name
celladdr = activecell.Address



prior.Sheets(sheetname).Activate
prior.Sheets(sheetname).Range(celladdr).Activate
current.Activate
'first
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
windWidth = Application.Width
windheight = Application.Height
' set size and location of a main workbook
Application.WindowState = xlNormal
Application.Top = 0
Application.Left = 0
Application.Width = windWidth / 2
Application.Height = windheight
'second
prior.Activate
Application.WindowState = xlNormal
Application.Top = 0
Application.Left = windWidth / 2
Application.Width = windWidth / 2
Application.Height = windheight
current.Activate

End If

Exit Sub
errhandler:
MsgBox ("Cannot find loaded workbook, please try again!")
End Sub
```